# Testng: how to get assertion infomation in testng listner?

Tags: java, testng

This is my testcase:

```
public class Demo2  {
    @Test
    public void dd() {
        assertThat("a").isEqualTo("b");
    }
}
```

and there is a class extends `TestListenerAdapter`:

```java
public class DemoListner extends TestListenerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onTestFailure(tr);
        // how could get the assertion fail  message  ("a is not equal to b")in here ?
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to get assertion fail message in the method `onTestFailure` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exceptions are stored in `ITestResult` itself. You could get the details using:

```java
Throwable t = tr.getThrowable();
// now you can use this throwable object to get the details..

//example
System.out.println(t.getMessage());
```